# Is there a way to create space between 2 elements without padding or margin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, react-native

I am using React Native and I have 2 inline buttons, the `search` and `add` buttons:

[image]

What I need is to create some space between these buttons without affecting the left and right edge.

This is how I am using the JSX:

```
    <View style={globalStyles.stretchContent}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          globalStyles.touchableBtnDropOffItem,
          { backgroundColor: Colors.dropOffTabColor },
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Search</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          globalStyles.touchableBtnDropOffItem,
          { backgroundColor: Colors.dropOffTabColor },
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Add</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

And the stylesheet:

```
  touchableBtnDropOffItem: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'space-between',
    height: 36,
    marginTop: 20,
    borderRadius: 2,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  stretchContent: {
    flex: 1,
    color: white,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
```

As you know React Native uses flexbox and I am having a hard time trying to achieve what I need. The thing is that if I apply margin, it will reduce the width of the buttons on the end of each one. For example: I need the search button to be completely aligned with the text `All Passengers List (9)`. If I apply `marginHorizontal` it will reduce the width, it will create a margin on both sides of the 2 buttons so it won't be aligned anymore with the text I mentioned.

So, what can I do in this case?

Comment: I am not sure about React, but the general idea would be to make the button smaller like 40% each and float the buttons right and left respectively which will give you space in between two buttons

Comment: https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#justify-content try space-between value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
  touchableBtnDropOffItem: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'space-between',
    height: 36,
    marginTop: 20,
    borderRadius: 2,
    flexBasis: 45%,
  },
  stretchContent: {
    flex: 1,
    color: white,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
```

add `flexBasis: 45%` to the button and add `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to the `stretchContent`.
`flexBasis` is something like width when used inside `flexbox`

Comment: Yep, this is what it worked for me. I had to remove `flex: 1` and `marginHorizontal: 5,` which was making the buttons to get full width.

Comment: great!! i edited the answer to better match your working solution if someone needed  it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is, keep a width for both the button and use `justifyContent: 'space-around'` and if want space in between button's left or right too use `justifyContent: 'space-between'`.

For your example,

```
touchableBtnDropOffItem: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'space-between',
    height: 36,
    marginTop: 20,
    borderRadius: 2,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
    width: '40%'
  },
  stretchContent: {
    flex: 1,
    color: white,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is set the buttons to have a width slightly less than half (`45%` or `40%`), then float each button (float `Search` to the left, and `Add` to the right):

(I think the below syntax is correct - if it's not valid React code, please tell me how to fix it).

```
<View style={globalStyles.stretchContent}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={[
      globalStyles.touchableBtnDropOffItem,
      { backgroundColor: Colors.dropOffTabColor; float: left; },
    ]}
  >
    <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Search</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity
    style={[
      globalStyles.touchableBtnDropOffItem,
      { backgroundColor: Colors.dropOffTabColor; float: right; },
    ]}
  >
    <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Add</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

And in the stylesheet:

```
  touchableBtnDropOffItem: {
    width: 45%,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'space-between',
    height: 36,
    marginTop: 20,
    borderRadius: 2,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
```